# Is there any time limit for writing comments on research article?

Tags: publications

I am from mathematics background, recently I came across an article published in 2009 in which certain classification problem is incomplete and inappropriately addressed, can I write comments on that research article after 7 years ?

Comment: I don't really understand, if the answer was "no" then how do you presume you would be prevented from doing so?

Comment: @Mehrdad - See the answer below. "Comments" in this context likely refers to a published comment in a journal (e.g., [this Nature comment](http://www.nature.com/news/misconduct-lessons-from-researcher-rehab-1.20029)), not just a comment on a post on a personal website.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, you can publish comments both informally (e.g. on a blog) and formally (by writing a paper that references the 2009 article) irrespective of when the original work was published. Much older articles get referenced and followed up upon.

The only issues to be aware of are:

- The authors are somewhat less likely to notice and react to the comments.
- Research on the topic may have gone on and your comments may be "old news", or already superseded of their own.

Comment: I.e., OP, keep looking for follow-up work that cites this 2009 paper pointing out the same or similar flaws that you already found!